Getting error Bearer error="invalid_token" while calling API using C# code
I was learning to authenticate API using Azure AD authentication this is the code which I configured on MVC side
public async Task<IEnumerable<Todo>> GetAsync()
{
    await PrepareAuthenticatedClient();

    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{ _TodoListBaseAddress}/api/todolist");

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        IEnumerable<Todo> todolist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Todo>>(content);

        return todolist;
    }

    throw new HttpRequestException($"Invalid status code in the HttpResponseMessage: {response.StatusCode}.");
}

private async Task PrepareAuthenticatedClient()
{
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { _TodoListScope });
    Debug.WriteLine($"access token-{accessToken}");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}

MVC appsettings.json file
{   
    "AzureAdB2C":  
    {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",     
        "Domain": "xxxx.com",     
        "TenantId": "4d5c2d64-35d8-4200-805e-xxxxxx11e",     
        "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout",     
        "ClientSecret": "MMA8Q\~T\~KwXpSqDscijieKycv7Zxxxxxxxxxt",     
        "ClientId": "c8db825e-be17-4943-b2e5-caxxxxx5"   
    },   
    "TodoList": 
    {     
         "TodoListScope": "tasks.read",     
         "TodoListBaseAddress": "https://localhost:44332"   
    },   
    "Logging": 
    {     
        "LogLevel":
        {       
            "Default": "Information",       
            "Microsoft": "Warning",       
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"     
        }   
    },   
    "AllowedHosts": "\*" 
}

Web API Startup file:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => {Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         ValidateLifetime = true,
         ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = true,
         ValidIssuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
         ValidAudience = "api://c8db825e-be17-4943-b2e5-caf39xxxx",
         IssuerSigningKey =
             new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                 Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret"])),
     };
     options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
     {
         OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
         {
             // Log detailed information about the failure
             Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {context.Exception}");
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         },
         OnChallenge = context =>
         {
             // Log detailed information about the challenge
             Console.WriteLine($"Challenge: {context.Error}, {context.ErrorDescription}");
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         }
     };
 },
 options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
 
    services.AddControllers();
}

Web API appsettings.json:
{   
    "AzureAdB2C": 
    {     
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",     
        "Domain": "xxxx.com",     
        "ClientId": "aeaaab9e-1040-4edf-9f31-5adc3xxxx",     
        "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/",     
        "TenantId": "4d5c2d64-35d8-4200-805e-9cdddxxxx",     
        "ClientSecret": "MMA8Q~T~KwXpSqDscijieKycv7ZWspsnxxxx"   
    },   
    "Kestrel": 
    {     
        "Endpoints": 
        {       
            "Http": 
            {         
                "Url": "https://localhost:44332"       
            }     
        }   
    },   
    "Logging": 
    {     
        "LogLevel": 
        {       
            "Default": "Warning"     
        }   
    },   
    "AllowedHosts": "*" 
}

This is the repo which I used to get code online https://github.com/learnsmartcoding/azure-ad-b2c-authentication-tutorial configuration for App registration is added for MVC application and Web API in Azure
I want that API should accept token generated from Azure AD user . I tried to configure details which I found online but API does not accept bearer token

Are you using Azure Ad or Azure B2C for your API?

I am using Azure AD

Did you try with swagger?

Yes tried but same issue persist., I am able to generate token but after passing token to web api it shows error as 401 unauthorize

I created an ASP. NET Core API and integrated Azure AD authentication using Swagger UI.
I added below code to Program.cs file.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    o =>
    {
        o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Swagger Azure Ad", Version = "v1" });
        o.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "oauth2.0",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:TokenUrl"]),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"],"Access API as User" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference=new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,Id="oauth2"}
                },
                new []{builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"]}
            }
        });
    });
app.UseSwaggerUI(
        o =>
        {
            o.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:ClientId"]);
            o.OAuthUsePkce();
            o.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        });
}

Below is the complete code of Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    o =>
    {
        o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Swagger Azure Ad", Version = "v1" });
        o.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "oauth2.0",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:TokenUrl"]),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"],"Access API as User" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference=new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,Id="oauth2"}
                },
                new []{builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"]}
            }
        });
    });
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        o =>
        {
            o.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:ClientId"]);
            o.OAuthUsePkce();
            o.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        });
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

appSettings.json:
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<YourDomain>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<YourTenantID>",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user"
  },
  "SwaggerAAD": {
    "AuthorizationUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "TokenUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "Scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>"
  }

I created two app registrations for Azure AD, one for the Web API and another for the Swagger client.
In the API App registration, go to Authentication -> Add a platform -> Web -> Redirect URI.
https:Localhost:Port/singin-oidc


In api Goto Expose an Api -> Add Scope. I added below details.

In swaggerclient App registration Goto Authentication -> Add Platform -> Single-Page application -> Redirect URL as shown below.
https:Localhost:Port/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html


In swaggerclient Goto API permission -> Add Permission -> My Apis -> api  -> Permission select your scope as shown below.


After running Click on the Authorize button.

Select the Scope and Click the Authorize button.

It is successfully logged in as shown below.

Output:

